# Parse file containing JSON objects into database using python

Tags: python, json, simplejson

I have a file containing in each row a JSON object, which means that the whole file is not a valid JSON, but only each row by itself is.

What I'm trying to do is to iterate through the file and convert each row into a JSON and then print the values, simple because only each row by itself is a valid JSON.

The file looks like this:

```
{json object 1}
{json object 2}
{json object 3}
{json object 4}
```

each JSON object looks like this:

```
{"event":"Session","properties":{"time":1423353612,"duration":33}}
```

The code I'm trying to run with no success is the following:

```
import simplejson as json
with open("sessions.json", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        j=json.JSONEncoder().encode(line)
        print j['event']['time']
        print j['event']['duration']
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

Any ideas why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the wrong thing. Converting from a JSON string to a Python object is *de*coding, not encoding. And in any case, it's better to use the top-level functions in the `json` module, rather than the underlying classes themselves.

```
for line in f:
    j = json.loads(line)
```

**Edit**

Given the structure you show, `j['event']` is the string "Session" and it does not have a sub-property `time`. Looks like you mean `j['properties']['time']`.